# Seeking files for older version of Chrome Dev

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, chromium

Anybody here using Chrome Dev channel on Windows?

https://i.ibb.co/zsdTdVT/image.png

If there is anybody willing to zip and upload folders inside C:/Program Files(x86)/Google/Chrome Dev/Application?

I need older versions of chrome for testing some apps, and there are no old versions available for download for Chrome dev (no regular Chrome).

Comment: See also https://www.chromium.org/developers/bisect-builds-py

Comment: I doubt we want to host questions here asking for executable files. That is a recipe for someone posting an answer containing malware.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not allow downloading previous versions of the browser. Even if you get an old version, it will automatically update to the latest version when you open the browser.

What you can do is to download a previous version of the Chromium browser [here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html), which is basically the same source with some modifications.

*Obs: this question should be posted on superuser.com. There are a lot of similar questions in there.*